# Como leer los datos de un Objeto php?

Tags: php, json

Estoy haciendo un proyecto donde estoy consumiendo un objeto que me envian con muchos datos. de la siguiente forma

```
$cliente = new SoapClient("webservice");
$respuesta = $cliente->metodo();
var_dump($respuesta);
```

Lo que me muestra la respuesta es algo similar a esto

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["metodoResultado"]=> string(3053)  "[{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001062210","Voucher":"AdFc02_137582","fecha":"2017-02-20","fecha2":"2017-03-22","monto":9752},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001062222","Voucher":"AdFc02_137590","fecha":"2017-02-20","fecha2":"2017-03-22","monto":38913},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001062295","Voucher":"AdFc02_137650","fecha":"2017-02-21","fecha2":"2017-03-29",monto":59942},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001062305","Voucher":"AdFc02_137659","fecha":"2017-02-21","fecha2":"2017-03-29","monto":30690},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001062346","Voucher":"AdFc02_137696","fecha":"2017-02-21","fecha2":"2017-03-29","monto":28139},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001062744","Voucher":"AdFc02_138017","fecha":"2017-02-24","fecha2":"2017-03-29","monto":12537},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001062884","Voucher":"AdFc02_138134","fecha":"2017-02-28","fecha2":"2017-04-05","monto":77261},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001063072","Voucher":"AdFc02_138292","fecha":"2017-03-02","fecha2":"2017-04-05","monto":48295},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001063358","Voucher":"AdFc02_138525","fecha":"2017-03-06","fecha2":"2017-04-05","monto":75229},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001063413","Voucher":"AdFc02_138573","fecha":"2017-03-07","fecha2":"2017-04-12","monto":10363},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001063519","Voucher":"AdFc02_138658","fecha":"2017-03-07","fecha2":"2017-04-12","monto":4093},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001063868","Voucher":"AdFc02_138937","fecha":"2017-03-11","fecha2":"2017-04-12","monto":10353},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001063884","Voucher":"AdFc02_138953","fecha":"2017-03-13","fecha2":"2017-04-12","monto":50194},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001063916","Voucher":"AdFc02_138976","fecha":"2017-03-13","fecha2":"2017-04-12","monto":54132},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001064023","Voucher":"AdFc02_139063","fecha":"2017-03-14","fecha2":"2017-04-19","monto":6323},{"cuenta":"001000","factura":"001064114","Voucher":"AdFc02_139143","fecha":"2017-03-15","fecha2":"2017-04-19","monto":9560}]"
```

Estos datos que me da de resultado como los trabajo en php para obtener la informacion en filas e inclusive separar los elementos? LLevo algunos días intentando muchas cosas, metodos pero aun nada. No logro comprender como hacer funcionar esto.

Gracias

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, de donde estas obteniendo los datos que quieres conformar de la forma del ejemplo que colocas. Una cosa mas tu lo que quieres es una respuesta en json para trabajarlo con jquery.

Comment: Hola, si es posible evitar el json y tirarlo todo en php me sería muy util, siguiendo con la respuesta de mas abajo, si yo hago '$metodoResultado=json_decode($respuesta->metodoResultado);' y hago un var_dump($metodoResultado[1]); me lanza solo un alinea pero para sacar los datos dee sa linea en ese punto como se accesan?

Comment: la mejor forma de tomar un objeto [metodoResultado][cuenta]

Answer (score 1):

La variable $respuesta efectivamente es un objeto pero dentro de esta se encuentra $respuesta->metodoResultado que es un string y para poder trabajar
como json tendrias que hacer esto:

```
 $metodoResultado=json_decode($respuesta->metodoResultado);
```

Pero primero te aconsejo revisar el método que te retorna el objeto porque te falta una comilla en un "monto" y eso te puede causar problemas al decodificar.

Comment: En efecto ja lo de la comilla, ahora me tira los datos de otra forma en JSON. Es posible utilizar los datos, trabajarlos directo sin entrar en el Json?

Comment: Claro, si todo te lo retorna como objeto, puedes manipularlos mediante la profundidad de los datos de esta manera:
 
$respuesta->metodoResultado[0]->cuenta
. . .
$respuesta->metodoResultado[0]->monto

Comment: En efecto si yo lanzo mas bien          $metodoResultado=json_decode($respuesta->metodoResultado); y hago un var_dump($metodoResultado[1]); me lanza solo un alinea pero para sacar los datos dee sa linea en ese punto como se accesan?

Answer (score 0):

```
Prueba con esto ya que es un Objeto :

    $cliente = new SoapClient("webservice");
    $respuesta = $cliente->metodo();
    $dato = var_dump($respuesta);
    $monto = $dato->monto;
    $Voucher = $dato->Voucher;
    $fecha= $dato->fecha;
    $fecha2= $dato->fecha2;
```

Comment: Si, pero ahi me lanza el Trying to get property of non-object